# Draw multiple image's on canvas with each image rotated

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm new into HTML5 programming and I wanted to know how to rotate each image when it is added into canvas. Should each of them be placed into a canvas and then rotated? If so how can i add multiple canvas into a single canvas context.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/G7ehG/

Code

```
function loadImages(sources, callback) {
        var images = {};
        var loadedImages = 0;
        var numImages = 0;
        // get num of sources
        for(var src in sources) {
          numImages++;
        }
        for(var src in sources) {
          images[src] = new Image();
          images[src].onload = function() {
            if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
              callback(images);
            }
          };
          images[src].src = sources[src];
        }
      }
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      var sources = {
        image1: 'http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2666/3686946460_0acfa289fa_m.jpg',
        image2: 'http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3611/3686140905_cbf9824a49_m.jpg'
      };

      loadImages(sources, function(images) {
        context.drawImage(images.image1, 100, 30, 200, 137);
        context.drawImage(images.image2, 350, 55, 93, 104);
      });
```

Comment: Try this link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411991/html5-canvas-rotate-image

Comment: This would work in case of only a single image where the whole canvas context is rotated. How would this work when you want multiple images rotated in different angles ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your comment you mentioned that you know about `context.rotate`, but you don't want the context to stay rotated. That's not a problem at all. First, calling `context.rotate` only affects things which are drawn afterwards. Anything drawn before will stay were it was. Second, it can be easily reversed after drawing.

1. use [`context.save()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#the-canvas-state) to create a snapshot of all current context settings, including current rotation.
2. use [`context.rotate(angle)`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#dom-context-2d-rotate) and draw your image. The angle is in [Radian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian). That means a full 360° circle is `Math.PI * 2`. The point the image will be is rotated around is the current origin of the canvas (0:0). When you want to rotate the image around its center, use [`context.translate(x, y)`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#dom-context-2d-translate) to set the origin to where you want the center of the image to be, then rotate, and then draw the image at the coordinates `-img.width/ 2, -img.height / 2`
3. use [`context.restore()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#the-canvas-state) to return to your snapshot. Rotation and translation will now be like they were before.

Here is an example function which draws an image rotated by 45° at the coordinates 100,100:

```
function drawRotated(image, context) {
    context.save();
    context.translate(100, 100);
    context.rotate(Math.PI / 4);
    context.drawImage(image, -image.width / 2, -image.height / 2);
    context.restore();
}
```

Comment: Change the function signature to drawRotated(context, img, x, y, angle) and this should be the answer. (and maybe set this method on CanvasRenderingContext2D's prototype ... ?)

Comment: @GameAlchemist Adding fields to objects or prototypes you didn't write can be dangerous, because there is a risk of overwriting fields which already exist.