# rotating a canvas after converting it to a image in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I have a `canvas` which I convert to a image like so,

```
var can = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.src = can.toDataURL();
```

I need to rotate this image now? Is it possible?

Comment: sorry,I dont think this is a duplicate. I need this to be done in js not in css. Because I transfer the image to new window when it is done rotating.

Comment: The second answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/29398757/1693593) where canvas size is reflected relative to rotation, is probably what you want in your case.

Comment: Solved it thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new canvas, rotate it's 2dDrawingContext, draw your image data to it, then set that as the source

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx2 = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx2.rotate(Math.PI/2);
ctx2.putImageData(ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height), 0, 0);
```

From there you can then call `ctx2.toDataURL()` and slap it in your image.