# JavaScript Canvas: Continuously rotating a canvas drawn image

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, html5-canvas, image-rotation

I am trying to rotate a sprite whilst maintaining the same position.

How would I go about **continuously** rotating this image drawn on the canvas?

My assumption would be calling a function using setInterval every 300ms for example, but I have no idea how to rotate a **single element** on the canvas continuously.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Dont know if this tutorial is good, just the first i found on google: [HTML5 Canvas Transformation State Stack Tutorial](https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-transformation-state-stack-tutorial/)

Comment: This tutorial allows for single-element rotation through the means of `context.save` and `context.restore`, however the I am still unable to **continuously** rotate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Animation and Rotating image

### Animation

To animate any content using the canvas you need to first set up an animation loop. Generally you use one animation loop to render all the canvas content.

The timing of an animation is controlled by time events created using [`requestAnimationFrame(callback)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) (RAF) This automatically calls the next frame in 1 / 60th of a second (if possible). You need to call RAF at some point in the animation loop.

Example of animation loop.

```
 function mainLoop(time) { // time is automatically passed to the function
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // clear canvas

      // draw what you need for the animation

      requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop); // set up the next frame
 }

 // to start the animation call RAF 
 requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop); // set up the next frame
```

### Rotate an image.

You can rotate an image around its center using the 2D context functions [`setTransform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/setTransform) and [`rotate`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/rotate)

`setTransform` overwrite the existing transform so you don't need to worry about the canvas state

To rotate about the image center you need to draw the image offset by half its with and height otherwise it will rotate around the top left corner.

Example function to rotate image

```
 function drawImageRotated(img, x, y, rot){
      ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, x, y); // set the scale and the center pos
      ctx.rotate(rot); // set the rotation
      ctx.drawImage(img, -img.width /2, -img.height /2); // draw image offset 
                                                         // by half its width
                                                         // and heigth
      ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // restore default transform
}
```

### Put it all together

The next example loads an image, sets up a canvas and using a main loop rotates the image. Note I added scale to the image draw function as the loaded image did not fit.

```js
const img = new Image();
img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7qq2.png?s=328&g=1";
img.onload = () => { requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop) } // start when loaded
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 

function drawImageRotated(img, x, y, scale, rot) {
  ctx.setTransform(scale, 0, 0, scale, x, y);
  ctx.rotate(rot);
  ctx.drawImage(img, -img.width / 2, -img.height / 2);
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}

function mainLoop(time) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawImageRotated(img,canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, 0.5, time / 500);
  requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Many tuts will use `save` and `restore`, and rotate the image via a set of translations, and rotations. This is very slow compared to using `setTransform`. Try to avoid using too many transformation calls and calls to [`save`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/save) and [`restore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/restore).

This [answer shows 500 images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43155027/3877726) rotated and scaled images using the same method. There is plenty of room to up the count if you are not using a slow device. Average laptops and desktops will do 1000+ at full frame rates.

Comment: Really helpful and informative answer, thanks for the help!