# JavaScript - rotate SVG based line's angle

Tags: javascript, canvas, rotation

I draw the line on Canvas and want to merge svg image on line based it's position. How can I find the angle between start and end points of draw line?

**Edit**

This function for get Angle of Line

```
 public angleOfWall(p1,p2){
var angleDeg = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) * 180 / Math.PI;
    return angleDeg;
 }

 var angleOfWall = this.angleOfWall(closestWall.getStart(), closestWall.getEnd());
```

After find the angle, I want to merge img to on it.

```
 for (let i = 0; i < this.model.floorplan.items.length; i++) {
       item = this.model.floorplan.items[i];

       var hover = item===this.viewmodel.activeItem;

      var itemWidth = item.width|32;
      var itemHeight = item.height|32;

      if (!item.el) {
        item.el = document.createElement('img');
        // draw door line on that position 
        item.el.src = this.model.floorplan.items[i].model_url_2d;
        item.el.onload = (( /** image **/ ) => {
          this.context.drawImage(item.el,
          this.viewmodel.convertX(item.xpos * item.scale_x) - itemWidth/2.,
          this.viewmodel.convertY(item.zpos * item.scale_z) - itemHeight/2.,
          itemWidth, itemHeight);
```

}
.("model_url2d" is SVG image's url )

```
      private rotateSVG(rotateSVG) {
    var innerArrow = document.getElementById("#add-items");
    innerArrow.setAttribute("transform", rotateSVG);
}
```

Is it right way to follow line rotate position? Just Im new in JS side so need some help. thanks

[here What I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHcPv.png)
but want to rotate img angle as line's angle

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. If you are asking a question here, it is strongly advised to add your attempt to solve your problem into this post. Thus, include the relevant code to begin with. Thanks.

Comment: OK, now that you've changed the question, how do you define the angle between a start and end point of a line ... for example, a line going from (4,4) to (5,5) has what angle? a line going from (6,6) to (3,3) has what angle? a line going from (1,2) to (2,1) has what angle? and a line going from (4,3) to (3,4) has what angle? If you can give an answer to that perhaps I can help

Comment: @JaromandaX  I edited question

Comment: `I already get the angle of line` - what? so now you have the angle?

Comment: Yes I have the line's angle in degrees

Comment: @Kaiido edit it again

Comment: No, this code doesn't generate the image you have. You don't show what rotateSVG is, nor how is declared your svg, nor anything even related to canvas. + I sincerily doubt you have an element which id's start by `#`.

Comment: ah sorry I forget about put here Canvas code, I edit it again :-) @Kaiido

Comment: ... so this svg you are trying to rotate is actually drawn on your canvas?

Comment: @JaromandaX could you help closing this as a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411991/html5-canvas-rotate-image? I already burnt my CV as too broad..

Comment: @Kaiido the issue is what I cannot rotate in canvas at all. In log I check how svg rotate is changing when merge with line. but in canvas its not showing

Comment: Yeah because what's in the <img> is not the same as what you have in your dom. You can't access the content of an img, so you have to handle the transform just like with a raster image.

Comment: @Kaiido but I see and drag that SVG image on canvas. Is it possible to dragg and drop, move in canvas <img>, but not possible to rotate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IMPORTANT: This answer addresses the question as of revision 1
This is the content of the question I answered:**

"**I draw the line on Canvas and want to merge svg image on line based it's position. How can I find the angle between start and end points of draw line?**"

Given 2 points p1 and p2 you may calculate the angle between start and end points of the line drawn from p1 to p2 using the [atan2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2) method.

If you consider the line as the hypotenuse and the distance in x (dx) & y (dy) as catheti you can write: `let angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);`. This will give you the angle in radians. If you need the angle in degrees you have to: `let angleInDegrees = angle*180/Math.PI`

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let cw = canvas.width = 300,
  cx = cw / 2;
let ch = canvas.height = 300,
  cy = ch / 2;

// given 2 points: p1 and p2
let p1 = {x:50, y:200},
    p2= {x:200, y:50}


ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
ctx.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);
ctx.stroke();

//the distance in x & y between the 2 points 
let dx = p2.x - p1.x;
let dy = p2.y - p1.y;


// the angle in radians
let angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);


// the angle in degrees
console.log(angle*180/Math.PI)
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid #d9d9d9;}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah I already get the angle in degrees as 

  public angleOfWall(p1,p2){
    // angle in radians
    var angleRadians = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x);
    // angle in degrees
    var angleDeg = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) * 180 / Math.PI;
    return angleDeg;
  }

Comment: but second issue is rotate svg image based line's angle

Comment: @muze You edited the question in base of my answer and change it to another question. If you liked my answer please consider accepting it and ask another question in a different post.