# Canvas Orientation Displaying Impropely

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas, orientation

I am getting some images displaying sideways that need to be turned due to EXIF metadata. I have used image-orientation: from-image to fix the img tags. What is the equivalent for a canvas tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS `image-orientation` is not well-supported, and the MDN documentation says it will likely be deprecated. If you know that all of the images are already rotated (in the same direction), you can either:

a.) open the images in an image editor such as GIMP and save over them (GIMP will overwrite the rotation data, providing you a warning first).

b.) Use the CSS `transform` property:

CSS

```css
.my-images-selector {

  /* 90deg or 270deg depending on the rotation */
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

If you are drawing an image onto an entire canvas, you can just apply the CSS above to the canvas element.

c.) For drawing rotated images within a canvas, use the canvas context `transform` method (you can refer here: [HTML5 Canvas Rotate Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411991/html5-canvas-rotate-image) )

Also, see [JS Client-Side Exif Orientation: Rotate and Mirror JPEG Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600800/js-client-side-exif-orientation-rotate-and-mirror-jpeg-images)

Comment: My problem is that I don't know how images need to be rerotated beforehand. We are displaying them after connecting to an s3 bucket.

Comment: ok, to answer your question there is no equivalent for drawing an image onto a canvas. `drawImage` ignores EXIF data, so documentation suggests determining the orientation and using canvas context `transform`method as I noted. It seems that the most preferred way to extract the data is by using exif.js: https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js

Comment: and if you were asking for a CSS-specific equivalent for canvas, it seems that the image-specific `image-orientation` property was marked for deprecation before any such equivalent could even be considered. (I doubt one would have ever been suggested though, as `<canvas>` has no need for its own element-specific CSS properties, as you have complete control with JavaScript over how things are drawn to it.)

Comment: @tlong314 I've found that using Chrome 83, `drawImage` does indeed use the EXIF data to draw the image to the canvas.  It will behave as though `image-orientation: from-image` is set.  I haven't found a way to change this through JavaScript as setting the style directly seems to be ignored.