# Get ImageData from imgurl using xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, image

There are similar questions, but the answers all use canvas. It'll be slow and I think it's *unnatural*.

I searched and it seemed that I can use `XMLHttpRequest`. But I tried all examples and failed (although I got some data,they failed to form `ImageData`).

```js
function getdata(){
    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.responseType="blob" // or something else?
    xhr.onload=function(){
        temp=xhr.response
    }
    xhr.open("GET","favicon.ico",true)
    xhr.send()
}
// what to do next?
```

EDIT: I shall repeat myself again : **no canvas**

Comment: You specifically want an ImageData object? Or you just want to read the image's data in some other format? You'd need an image parser, currently the only "built-in" way is a canvas, not sure what you find "unnatural" in that. We are discussing adding an [ImageBitmap.getImageData])(https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/4785)  method, but it's not done yet.

Comment: Well, I need to do some operations . For example change the color of specific pixels before showing.

Comment: And that is exactly one of the goals the canvas had been made for, why can't you use a canvas?

Comment: Because the same thing well be drawn several times (just imagine a 2d minecraft) , it'll be _very_ slow if it is done on canvas.

Comment: No, it will be slower if done yourself ;-p if you need to prepare multiple sprites, do just that: **prepare** mutliple sprites. Whatever time is spent pn the canvas will be like nothing compared to the time spent fetching then parsing and decoding the images.

Comment: Drawing on canvas needs fetching, parsing and decoding too. And what if I want to change every pixel of the image, and I want to draw many times? Is it still slow? If it turns out it is, I'll try your way.

Comment: To do pixel manipulation in the browser the canvas will be the fastest way, it has direct access to the GPU. Whatever solution you'll be using without a canvas will be stuck on the CPU. GPUs are made to do this job, the canvas is made to do this job, use a canvas.

Comment: now i want to rotate the img and drawimage can't do it

Comment: of course it can... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411991/html5-canvas-rotate-image

Comment: but this affects other parts of the canvas

Comment: no it doesn't. You can simply reset the transformation matrix after. Please go check tutorials, stop with your preconception that X can't be done, search how to do it first.

Comment: i tried one of the answers and failed :( maybe i tried a wrong one

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Load Image</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="my_image"/>
        <canvas id="my_canvas"></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            loadImage();
            var blob;
            var blobUrl;
            async function loadImage() {

                var url = "http://.../image.png";
                blob = await makeRequest("GET", url);
                console.log("blob: ", blob);
                console.log("blob size: ", blob.size);
                console.log("blob type: ", blob.type);
                console.log("createObjectURL: ", URL.createObjectURL(blob));
                blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                console.log("blobUrl: ", blobUrl);
                getImageData(blob);
                document.querySelector('#my_image').src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            }

            function makeRequest(method, url) {
                return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open(method, url,true);
                    xhr.responseType="blob"
                    xhr.onload = function () {
                        if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
                            resolve(xhr.response);
                        } else {
                            reject({
                                status: this.status,
                                statusText: xhr.statusText
                            });
                        }
                    };
                    xhr.onerror = function () {
                        reject({
                            status: this.status,
                            statusText: xhr.statusText
                        });
                    };
                    xhr.send();
                });
            }

            var imageData;
            getImageData = async function(blob){

                const bitmap = await createImageBitmap(blob);
                const [width, height] = [bitmap.width, bitmap.height];

                var newCanvas = document.getElementById('my_canvas');
                var ctx = newCanvas.getContext('2d');

                //ctx.drawImage(bitmap, width, height);
                console.log("bitmap: ", bitmap);
                
                //ImageData Object
                imageData = ctx.createImageData(width, height);
                console.log("imageData: ", imageData);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: works well except... where's the `ImageData` ?

Comment: Which data do you need from the image?

Comment: in case you don't know, there's a data type called [ImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData)

Comment: I editet the code. ImageData is in the getImageData() function

Comment: I said I didn't want canvas. So this is the only way?

Comment: `getImageData` not `createImageData` at the end, or your ImageData will be empty.

Comment: It's just a dummy canvas to get the context. @Kaiido: If you take a look in the developer console, you will see that ImageData is not empty.

Comment: @TomInCode it is, all values are 0.