# Canvas rotated shapes on a circle's edge

Tags: javascript, html

Does anyone know how to rotate these smiles like this, with JavaScript.
[image]

I can't seem to think of what to do in my head. I think it has to do with loops.

Also this is my code for the smile.

```
function drawSmile(x,y){

    ctx.fillStyle = "yellow"
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc(x,y,50, 0, 2*Math.PI) // Yellow initial circle
    ctx.stroke()
    ctx.fill()
    
    ctx.fillStyle = "black"
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc(x,y,20, 0, Math.PI) //smile
    ctx.stroke()
    
    ctx.fillStyle = "black"
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc(x-20,y-20,10,0,2*Math.PI) // eyeball left
    ctx.stroke()
    ctx.fill()
    
    ctx.fillStyle = "black"
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc(x+20,y-20,10,0,2*Math.PI) // eyeball right
    ctx.stroke()
    ctx.fill()

}
```

Comment: PS: since you still have not, please take a [tour] to learn how this site works. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5 Canvas Rotate Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411991/html5-canvas-rotate-image)

Answer (score 4):

## Draw the same (rotated) shape or image *n* times on a circle's circumference

Instead of drawing every smiley part at some `x/y` coordinates, always draw the smileys in the same place. **Instead, translate the canvas context**. Also pass the angle (radians) argument to your `drawSmile` function:

```js
const size = 350; // Desired canvas size
const center = size / 2;

const ctx = document.querySelector("#canvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.canvas.width = size;
ctx.canvas.height = size;

const PI = Math.PI;
const TAU = PI * 2;

const drawSmile = (x, y, ang) => {

  ctx.save();           // Save the current context
  ctx.translate(x, y);  // translate it to a new position
  ctx.rotate(ang);      // rotate it before drawing

  // Yellow initial circle
  ctx.fillStyle = "yellow"
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, 50, 0, TAU);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fill();

  // Smile
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, 30, 0, PI);
  ctx.stroke();

  // Eyeball left
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(-20, -20, 10, 0, TAU);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fill();

  // Eyeball right
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(+20, -20, 10, 0, TAU);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.restore(); // add this to restore the context to the saved values
};

const elTotal = document.querySelector("#total");
const elRadius = document.querySelector("#radius");

const draw = () => {

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

  const radius = elRadius.value ?? 1;
  const total = elTotal.value ?? 1;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    const ang = TAU / total * i; // Angle in radians
    const x = center + radius * Math.cos(ang);
    const y = center + radius * Math.sin(ang);
    drawSmile(x, y, ang);
  }
};

// Events:
elTotal.addEventListener("input", () => draw());
elRadius.addEventListener("input", () => draw());
// Init:
draw();
```

```html
Total:  <input id=total  type=number min=1 max=200 value=5>
Radius: <input id=radius type=number min=1 max=200 value=100><br>
<canvas id=canvas></canvas>
```